# Django - Error al aplicar attributos al input codigo en FORMS.PY

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

No le aplica estilo bootstrap al input codigo en el forms.py

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Station

class CrearEstacionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Station
        fields = ('__all__')
        widget = {
            'codigo': forms.TextInput(
                attrs = {
                    'class':'form-control'
                }
            )
        }
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Station
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    CreateView,
)
from .forms import CrearEstacionForm

def station_list(request):
    stations = Station.objects.filter().order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'station/station_list.html', {'stations': stations})


class StationAdd(CreateView):
    template_name = 'station/add.html'
    model = Station
    form_class = CrearEstacionForm
    success_url = '/'
```

template.html

```
{% block content %}
<h3 class="text-primary">Nueva Estacion</h3>

<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p}}

    <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

El widget está mal, se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Station

    class CrearEstacionForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Station
            fields = ('__all__')
            widgets = {
            'codigo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
            }
```

Comment: no olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada. ganaras 2 puntos de reputacion